# Web Applications and Software Licenses

Tags: license, web-application

I don't know many details of software licensing, but I'm basically wondering if (open source) software licenses can be applied to web applications (and open source themes and scripts and stuff like that), or if another type of license or legal document would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web applications are made from software, so yes they can use the software licenses.

Comment: @thenickperson However there are certain differences with web applications. I recommend that you red http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html Some of the differences are explained in that article.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, I just wanted to make sure. And are there any important details you can summarize to me if you don't mind? I'd rather not read a whole legal document, I don't think I'd understand it.